# Filtering ID's based on specified difference in values

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, difference

I am trying to filter IDs based on a specified conditions. For instance, I want to filter IDs which have a particular difference in questionnaire score from pre to post treatment. The idea is to get IDs that have improved in score, have stayed the same or have worsened. Here is a mock data set of what I'm trying to achieve:-

```
    ID<-c("aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","fff","ggg","hhh","iii","aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","fff","ggg","hhh","iii","aaa","bbb","ccc","aaa","bbb","ccc")
    Condition<-c("Pre","Pre","Pre","Pre","Pre","Pre","Pre","Pre","Pre","Post","Post","Post","Post","Post","Post","Post","Post","Post","Pre","Pre","Pre","Post","Post", "Post")
    Score<-c(23,20,19,15,22,22,20,19,18,17,17,19,20,22,22,14,15,10,23,23,21,20,18,11)
    df<-cbind(ID,Condition,Score)
    df<-as.data.frame(df)
    df$Condition<-as.factor(df$Condition)
```

The main issue here is that there are ID's who appear in the data, for both pre and post, twice.

I have tried using a `dplyr` solution to select the appropriate columns from the main data frame, and then use `tidyverse`, and the `spread` function to convert to wide format, because from there I can work out the differences easily enough. However, there is a particular problem that I've experienced. It wouldn't work because there are duplicate instances where an ID has appeared in the data again (for example, IDs aaa, bbb & ccc).

```
     df2<-df%>%
     group_by(ID)%>%
     spread(Condition, Score)
```

This gets me the following error message:-

> Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
>   Keys are shared for 12 rows:
>   * 10, 22
>   * 11, 23
>   * 12, 24
>   * 1, 19
>   * 2, 20
>   * 3, 21
>   Do you need to create unique ID with tibble::rowid_to_column()?

Ideally, the kind of result I would be looking for is like so:-

```
    #improved
    ID      Pre       Post     Difference
    aaa      23        17           -6
    bbb      20        17           -3
    ggg      20        14           -6
    hhh      19        15           -4
    iii      18        10           -8
    aaa      23        20           -3
    bbb      23        18           -5
    ccc      21        11           -10


    #no improvement
    ID      Pre       Post      Difference
    ccc      19         19          0
    eee      22         22          0
    fff      22         22          0


    #worsened
    ID      Pre       Post      Difference
    ddd      15         20          +5
```

Or something to this effect. As long as it allows me to include the repeated IDs. Ideally, I would like to be able to conditionally filter further based on the magnitude of difference. So for instance, if I want to subset/filter IDs with an improved score of more than 5, or a worsened score of more than 5. Bare in mind, my actual data set will have far more IDs to work with than the example that I just made up and provided. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as always.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers address `Score` being a factor due to the `cbind()` call. Here are solutions for Base R, data.table, and dplyr.

All of the solutions address the duplicate `ID` by adding an additional `Group` variable. This allows the `spread` to be successful.

```
# Base R ------------------------------------------------------------------

df <- data.frame(ID, Condition, Score)
df$Group <- ave(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$Condition, FUN = seq_along)

df_wide <- reshape(df, timevar = 'Condition', idvar = c('ID', 'Group'), direction = 'wide')
df_wide$Difference <- df_wide$Score.Post - df_wide$Score.Pre
df_wide[order(df_wide$Difference),]

# data.table --------------------------------------------------------------
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(ID, Condition, Score)
dt[, Group := seq_len(.N), by = Condition]

dt_wide <- dcast(dt, ID + Group ~ Condition, value.var = 'Score')
dt_wide[, Difference := Post - Pre]
dt_wide[order(Difference),]

# dplyr -------------------------------------------------------------------
library(tidyverse)

tib <- tibble(ID, Condition, Score)

tib%>%
  group_by(Condition)%>%
  mutate(Group = row_number())%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  spread(key = 'Condition', value = 'Score')%>%
  mutate(Difference = Post - Pre)%>%
  arrange(Difference)
```

For this *very* small dataset, base R is fastest and data.table is slowest.

```
Unit: milliseconds
           expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
     base_r_way 2.7562 2.98075 3.103155 3.05140 3.12810  6.0653   100
 data.table_way 6.6137 7.09705 8.216043 7.44250 8.01885 47.9138   100
      dplyr_way 4.7334 5.15005 5.350857 5.25085 5.40395  9.5594   100
```

And data:

```
ID <- c("aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","fff","ggg","hhh","iii","aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","fff","ggg","hhh","iii","aaa","bbb","ccc","aaa","bbb","ccc")
Condition <- c("Pre","Pre","Pre","Pre","Pre","Pre","Pre","Pre","Pre","Post","Post","Post","Post","Post","Post","Post","Post","Post","Pre","Pre","Pre","Post","Post", "Post")
Score <- as.integer(c(23,20,19,15,22,22,20,19,18,17,17,19,20,22,22,14,15,10,23,23,21,20,18,11))
```

Answer (score 2):

An option would be to first convert the 'Score' to `numeric` from `factor`, grouped by 'ID' 'Condition', create a sequence column ('rn'), `spread` to 'wide' format, get the diifference of 'Post' and 'Pre'  Scores, and `split` by the `sign` of 'Difference' column to create a `list` of `tibble`s

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   mutate(Score = as.numeric(as.character(Score))) %>% 
   group_by(ID, Condition) %>% 
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
   spread(Condition, Score) %>% 
   mutate(Difference = Post -Pre) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   select(-rn) %>%
   group_split(grp = sign(Difference), keep = FALSE)
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 8 x 4
#  ID     Post   Pre Difference
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 aaa      17    23         -6
#2 aaa      20    23         -3
#3 bbb      17    20         -3
#4 bbb      18    23         -5
#5 ccc      11    21        -10
#6 ggg      14    20         -6
#7 hhh      15    19         -4
#8 iii      10    18         -8

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  ID     Post   Pre Difference
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 ccc      19    19          0
#2 eee      22    22          0
#3 fff      22    22          0

#[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 x 4
#  ID     Post   Pre Difference
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 ddd      20    15          5
```

NOTE: It is not advisable to use `as.data.frame(cbind`, as `cbind` converts to a `matrix` and `matrix` can hold only a single class, i.e.if there is a character column, all the other columns get converted to `character` and wrapping with `as.data.frame` (default option is `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`).

```
df <- data.frame(...) #directly create
```

Answer (score 2):

A different `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
 mutate(Score = as.numeric(Score)) %>%
 group_by(Condition) %>%
 mutate(ID = make.unique(ID)) %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 mutate(Difference = Score - lag(Score)) %>%
 spread(Condition, Score) %>%
 summarise_all(max, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
 arrange(Difference)

   ID    Difference  Post   Pre
   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 ccc.1        -10    11    21
 2 iii           -8    10    18
 3 aaa           -6    17    23
 4 ggg           -6    14    20
 5 bbb.1         -5    18    23
 6 hhh           -4    15    19
 7 aaa.1         -3    20    23
 8 bbb           -3    17    20
 9 ccc            0    19    19
10 eee            0    22    22
11 fff            0    22    22
12 ddd            5    20    15
```

Here it, first, creates unique IDs. Second, it calculates the difference. Finally, it transforms it into a wide format and arranges it according the differences.

If for some reasons you need to split it according differences, you can add the last line from @akrun's code:

```
df %>%
 mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
 mutate(Score = as.numeric(Score)) %>%
 group_by(Condition) %>%
 mutate(ID = make.unique(ID)) %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 mutate(Difference = Score - lag(Score)) %>%
 spread(Condition, Score) %>%
 summarise_all(max, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
 group_split(sign(Difference), keep = FALSE)

[[1]]
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  ID    Difference  Post   Pre
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 aaa           -6    17    23
2 aaa.1         -3    20    23
3 bbb           -3    17    20
4 bbb.1         -5    18    23
5 ccc.1        -10    11    21
6 ggg           -6    14    20
7 hhh           -4    15    19
8 iii           -8    10    18

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  ID    Difference  Post   Pre
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 ccc            0    19    19
2 eee            0    22    22
3 fff            0    22    22

[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  ID    Difference  Post   Pre
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 ddd            5    20    15
```